beam_defo_interp_3d in openseespy
I have modeled a 3D frame in openseespy. After getting the nodal displacements and rotations (using node recorder in opensees), I want to reach to the interpolated displacements (using Hermitian shape function method) on beam elements in openseespy.
In other words, I want to get the coordinate of any point located on beam element. This will be conducted using the beam_defo_interp_3d() in opsvis but as there is no documentation for this command I want someone to help me in this area. I want to reach to the coordinates of a number of points on the deformed shape of the element. I will be very thankful, If someone can propose an example for me in this area. I want some clarification on how to use beam_defo_interp_3d() command because the help for this command in opsvis is not clear and there is no example for this command.
